# Remove entry from user's rss reader

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed, google-reader

I realized pretty simple atom feed in my application.
Sometimes records expire and are no longer published in the feed.
Is there a way to remove entry from user`s reader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used GUID/ID* elements in the feed, then posting a blank item with the same GUID as the deleted post will update the post in Google Reader with the blank content.

https://superuser.com/questions/446845/is-it-possible-to-prevent-deleted-posts-from-appearing-in-blog-readers-like-goog

http://support.google.com/reader/answer/69998?hl=en

Whether any other feed aggregators will update the post ( or even cache the old posts to begin with) 
is up to them.

- GUID for RSS 2.0 , ID for Atom